# Is there any way to retrieve the .py and other files from an already deployed app in SAP CF?

Tags: python, sap-cloud-platform

I had deployed a python app on the SAP CF to create a REST API. Is there any way to download the contents of the app from the CF platform?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/ssh-apps.html#other-ssh-access

Apparently CF allows you to ssh into your deployed apps and potentially execute scp/sftp commands.

Not sure this will be working on SAP CP for CF but that’s a lead to follow.

Let us know if that worked

Comment: I tried, till the 4th step fetches an error: 
Command: scp -P 2222 -o User=cf:abcdefab-1234-5678-abcd-1234abcd1234/0 ssh.MY-DOMAIN.com:REMOTE-FILE-TO-RETRIEVE LOCAL-FILE-DESTINATION

Error: ssh: Could not resolve hostname ssh.cf.eu10.hana.ondemand.com:app.py: No such host is known.

Here app.py is the name of the file I want to retrieve. Can you help me point out my mistake.

Comment: I just tried it with the app router and the access worked with both approach and it worked fine.
I think your mistake come from the syntax used for the command, as I can see that the app.py is included in the host name.
Here is one example that worked for me: "scp -P 2222 -o User=cf:<app guid>/<insatnce index starting at 0> ssh.cf.eu10.hana.ondemand.com:/home/vcap/staging_info.yml .". Make sure to adjust the path to your app.py file